# Dynamics 365 and SharePoint On-premise server side integration with AD username or UserID

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I have integrated MS Dynamics 365 & SharePoint Server but the default "SPClaimTypeMapping" is by email:

```
New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" -SameAsIncoming
```

But I need to map the users by Active Directory user (name or id).

I was trying to do this by running this command:

```
New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "UserName" -SameAsIncoming
```

No success and I get exceptions like this:

```
    Exception message: No Microsoft Dynamics 365 user exists with the specified domain name and user ID
   at Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.Claims.AuthenticationProvider.GetOrganizationId(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
```

I have read many many documents but nothing is clearly stated a mapping for AD (not ADFS or IFD ,etc.)

Note: Both servers are on the same domain.

Thanks